# Nslookup and finger command

Tags: nslookup, finger

Usually when I try finger on nslookup of Linux version said "still not implemented"
Finally I found a system which implement the finger nslookup command, but give me this error

```
nslookup 
Default Server:  sinix.mydom.priv
Address:  192.168.200.5

> finger myuser
Finger: no current host defined.
> finger myuser@sinix.mydom.priv
Unrecognized command: finger myuser@sinix.mydom.priv
> finger sinix
Finger: no current host defined.
> finger sinix.mydom.priv
Finger: no current host defined.
>
```

How to use finger option of nslookup command?